# Other simple proofs to derive the rotation formulas (for students of an high school)

Tags: analytic-geometry, alternative-proof, rotations

Given a cartesian reference system that in the diagram I have indicated with capital letters $OXY$ (in black) imagine to rotate it by an angle $α$ counterclockwise (positive angle):

[image]

N.B. the name of the axes has been indicated with capital letters, while the coordinates of point $P$ (in the two reference systems) have been indicated with the lower case ones. Given the following construction:

[image]

The $hx$ segment is given by:

$$hx = x'\cos(α)$$

while the $oh$ segment is given by:

$$oh = y'\sin(α)$$

The $ox$ segment, which is none other than the $x$ abscissa is given by:

$$x = oh - hx = y'\sin(α) - x'\cos(α)$$

This relationship connects the two reference systems. In the same way we calculate the ordinate $y$ by the following construction:

[image]

The $by$ segment is given by:

$$by = x'\sin(α)$$

while the $ob$ segment is given by:

$$ob = y'\cos(α)$$

from which you have:

$$y = ob + by = y'\cos(α) + x'\sin(α)$$

In summary:

$$x = y'\sin(α) - x'\cos(α)$$

$$y = y'\cos(α) + x'\sin(α)$$

This is the proof that I give for my students for the rotation.

> Are there other simple and more fast proofs? Everyone that every user to know is welcome.

Comment: Another simple way to visualize a rotating frame would be express the the $x$-axis in polar coordinates as $ {\bf x} = \left[ \textrm{cos}(\alpha), \ \textrm{sin}(\alpha) \right]^T$, then show that the $y$-axis is the solution to ${\bf x}^T {\bf y} = 0$, subject to $\textrm{det}\left(\left[ {\bf x} \ \ {\bf y} \right]\right) = 1$. This way you touch on why rotations are  *orthogonal* and *special*.

Comment: @tommym I have forgotten that the question it is for students of an high school. Now I have improved the title. However thank you very much.

Comment: To be honest, I'd go for polar coordinates; using the addition formulas ***is*** good and also showing the relations between two coordinate systems. My preference would go to applying complex numbers, actually.

Comment: @egreg I too have seen a solution with polar coordinates, or rather relationships that link polar coordinates with Cartesian ones. But the students don't understand it, they just want calculations and numerical examples. In the meantime I am preparing the entry tests with Google Suite :-(...Your answers are always very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your students prerequisite knowledge, there is a simpler way:

1. Establish that rotation is linear.
2. Show that rotation by $\alpha$ counterclockwise rotates the vector $(1,0)$ to $(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)$ and $(0,1)$ to $(-\sin\alpha,\cos\alpha)$. (similar to what you did, but simpler to draw and understand, imho)
3. Use this to find the matrix representation $\begin{pmatrix}x'\\y'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\alpha&-\sin\alpha\\ \sin\alpha&\cos\alpha\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$

Keep in mind, though, that I described how to find the formula for an [active transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation), that is, how to rotate a vector within the given coordinate system. What you did was a passive transformation, rotating the coordinate system. The difference is just that to find the coordinates after a passive transformation, you have to apply the inverse of the above matrix instead.

Comment: Thank you very much also to you. In the 2nd year of this school the students not studied the matrix. Impressive :-(. I have understood all your answer. +1

Comment: you have a sign mistake in the matrix!

Comment: @Physor: OP rotated the coordinate system (which I didn't notice until now), while I rotated the points within the coordinate system. That's where the different signs come from, probably.

Comment: @Physor: Wikipedia has surprisingly few mentions of the form rotation matrices take, but there is one here under *Symmetry group of spheres*: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group#In_Euclidean_geometry If the minus were at one of the cosines, we would get a rotation plus a reflection, and if the minus were at the other sine, we would get clockwise rotation.

Comment: Here we are not changing the vector, but the basis and so the components. But your matrix is doing the opposite. Consider the angle $\alpha$ in the diagrams. Put the vector $(0,1)$ on the right. then you get $(\cos \alpha, \sin \alpha)$ on the left. Both component are positive. But in the rotated *system* the first vector should have *negative* $y$-component. Again, your rotate the *vector*, but the question is about rotating the *system*, and changing the components

Comment: @Physor We're not really disagreeing. Yes, there is a difference between rotating the coordinate system or the vectors described by the coordinate system. But they're similar enough that OP seems to be satisfied with the answer. But I'm going to add a mention of it to my answer to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use polar coordinates and the angle addition formulas. The case $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is trivial, now for $(x,y)\neq(0,0),$ let $(x,y)=(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta)).$

Then $$(x',y')=(r\cos(\theta+\alpha),r\sin(\theta+\alpha))$$
$$=(r\cos(\theta)\cos(\alpha)-r\sin(\theta)\sin(\alpha),r\sin(\theta)\cos(\alpha)+r\cos(\theta)\sin(\alpha))$$
$$=(x\cos(\alpha)-y\sin(\alpha),x\sin(\alpha)+y\cos(\alpha)).$$

Comment: Thank you very much....for your efforts...+1...surely. For me it is very clear but I would to start only by $\sin$ and $\cos$ without to use addition formula of the $\cos$.

Comment: I've found [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h11ljFJeaLo) and [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8XRvpDhTJpw). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use scalar prodact
$$
\mathbf{r} = x\ \mathbf{\hat x} +y\ \mathbf{\hat y} = x'\ \mathbf{\hat x}' +y'\mathbf{\hat y}'
$$
$$
\mathbf{\hat x}'\cdot \mathbf{\hat x}'=1,\qquad \mathbf{\hat y}'\cdot \mathbf{\hat y}'=1,\qquad \mathbf{\hat x}'\cdot \mathbf{\hat y}'=\mathbf{\hat y}'\cdot \mathbf{\hat x}'=0
$$
$$
\mathbf{r}\cdot \mathbf{\hat x}' = x' = x\ \mathbf{\hat x}\cdot \mathbf{\hat x}' +y\ \mathbf{\hat y}\cdot \mathbf{\hat x}'\\
\mathbf{r}\cdot \mathbf{\hat y}' = y' = x\ \mathbf{\hat x}\cdot \mathbf{\hat y}' +y\ \mathbf{\hat y}\cdot \mathbf{\hat y}'
$$
The rotation is considered *from* $\mathbf{\hat x}$ *to* $\mathbf{\hat x}'$ by an angle $\alpha$
$$
\mathbf{\hat x}\cdot \mathbf{\hat x}'=\cos \alpha,\qquad \mathbf{\hat y}\cdot \mathbf{\hat y}'=\cos \alpha,\qquad \mathbf{\hat x}\cdot \mathbf{\hat y}'= \cos (\alpha+\frac{\pi}{2}) \qquad \mathbf{\hat y}\cdot \mathbf{\hat x}'= \cos (\alpha-\frac{\pi}{2})
$$
Recall that
$$
\cos(\alpha+\beta) = \cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta
$$
that means
$$
\cos (\alpha-\frac{\pi}{2})= +\sin\alpha \qquad \cos (\alpha-\frac{\pi}{2})=-\sin\alpha
$$

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use cosine addition formulas. Perhaps if they understand the last relationships that a function is shifted to right by $\pi/2$. :-( Thank you very very much.

Comment: your welcome! :)

Comment: No, :-) you have $x'$. I have $x$ in LHS. :-) are the inverse or direct :-) formulas.

Comment: I am a scarse prof. :-)...

Comment: But the answer with the matrix has a mistake, the signs of the $\sin$s should be reversed

Comment: It is not possible: $\det(M)=1$. It is correct.

Comment: check it, it has different signs for the sin$\alpha$

Comment: I will wait...you have written to @Vercassivelaunos.

Answer (score 1):

I have thought to this alternative solution:

Let $P\equiv(x,y)$ in the reference system $xOy$ and let $$\vec{OP}=x\hat{\bf x}+y\hat{\bf y}\equiv (x,y)$$ the displacement vector. In the reference system $XOY$ let,
$$\vec{OP}=X\hat{\bf X}+Y\hat{\bf Y}\equiv (X,Y)$$

Hence: $$\vec{OP}=x\hat{\bf x}+y\hat{\bf y}=X\hat{\bf X}+Y\hat{\bf Y}\tag 1$$
We suppose to rotate in anticlockwise the old reference system $xOy$ of an angle $\theta$.
I play with the colours (red vectors and dotted lines) of the triangles generate by $\hat{\bf X}$ and $\hat{\bf Y}$.

[image]

We have hence:

$$\hat{\bf X}=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)=\cos\theta\hat{\bf x}+\sin\theta\hat{\bf y}$$
taking the right square triangle for $\hat{\bf X}$. Taking the left triangle for $\hat{\bf Y}$ comparing the lenghts, it is evident that:

$$\hat{\bf Y}=(-\sin \theta,\cos \theta)=-\sin\theta\hat{\bf x}+\cos\theta\hat{\bf y}$$

Definitively from the $(1)$,

$$\vec{OP}=X\hat{\bf X}+Y\hat{\bf Y}=X(\cos\theta\hat{\bf x}+\sin\theta\hat{\bf y})+Y(-\sin\theta\hat{\bf x}+\cos\theta\hat{\bf y})$$
and being that

$$x\hat{\bf x}+y\hat{\bf y}=\vec{OP}\equiv (X\cos\theta-Y\sin\theta)\hat{\bf x}+(X\sin\theta+Y\cos\theta)\hat{\bf y}$$
we have, definitively:

\begin{cases}
x=X\cos\theta-Y\sin\theta &\\
y=X\sin\theta+Y\cos\theta
\end{cases}